# SeaFile HTML Customization

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, file-sharing, html

I have installed Seafile on Windows Server 2012 R2 Successfully.

I am now currently branding the install and have changed the logo/colours fine.

However, I wish to override some of the HTML (Like the footer for example) and I cannot get this to work?
I am using CE version 5.0.3.

I have the software downloaded to `C:\SeaFile\sefile-server-5.0.3` and have it installed on `K:\seafile-server\`

Currently my custom css is @ `C:\SeaFile\seafile-server-5.0.3\seahub\media\custom\site.css` and it works fine, and linked up the logo in the settings.py

However, I have followed the guide to create a /templates/ folder in custom but cannot change the footer at all?
How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably not the correct solution, but I have found that editing the template files directly (i.e. not moving them to a custom folder first) works flawlessly